# VMTK custom script producing "No module named: vmtk.custom" error

Tags: python, conda

I'm working with a module called VMTK to build scripts for analyzing vascular models. [They have a tutorial for writing these scripts](http://www.vmtk.org/tutorials/PypesAdvanced.html) so they're easily identifiable by the system allowing you to pipe scripts together known as PypeS. I've followed the tutorial *exactly* as shown and end up with the same "No module named: vmtk.name_of_script" error.

What I've tried:

- Putting the script in the same directory as all the preloaded scripts provided by the module so `__init__.py` could catch it
- Copy-pasting the code from the website into my editor so I'm sure there are no errors in what I've written
- Submitting the question directly onto the forum meant for questions about VMTK, with no responses for the past week and a half
- Changing my Python interpreter to the one within the VMTK directory

The tutorial says you can put the custom script anywhere in your filesystem, but the issue arises no matter what. I'm currently using Python 3.6.10 through Anaconda and a binary install of VMTK (as opposed to building from source) on MacOS High Sierra.

I *really* don't want to have to build from source, as I only need the preloaded scripts and ability to write new scripts, as opposed to using the C++ files that the scripts are built from. I've been stuck for so long and am not at all sure what the issue is. The closest thing I found was an SO question addressing this problem, but the OP simply said the problem had been resolved and provided no other information.

Here's the aforementioned code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

from vmtk import pypes
from vmtk import vmtkscripts

customscript = 'customScript'

class customScript(pypes.pypeScript):

    def __init__(self):
        pypes.pypeScript.__init__(self)

    def Execute(self): 
        pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    main = pypes.pypeMain()
    main.Arguments = sys.argv
    main.Execute()
```

As per the tutorial, I've also run `chmod u+x customscript.py` to change the permissions of my file so I can execute it. I get stuck at exactly the point where the script should do the most basic of operations within VMTK. Any ideas?

Edit: Here's the exact error:

```
$ ./customscript.py 

No module named 'vmtk.customscript'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vmtk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vmtk/pype.py", line 290, in Execute
    module = importlib.import_module('vmtk.'+scriptName)
  File "/vmtk/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vmtk.customscript'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./customscript.py", line 21, in <module>
    main.Execute()
  File "/vmtk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vmtk/pypescript.py", line 688, in Execute
    pipe.Execute()
  File "/vmtk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vmtk/pype.py", line 298, in Execute
    self.PrintError(str(e))
  File "/vmtk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vmtk/pype.py", line 102, in PrintError
    raise RuntimeError(errorMessage)
RuntimeError: No module named 'vmtk.customscript'
```

I want to backtrace the issue but I don't think editing any of the preloaded files should be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found after a week of trying and searching:

1. `git clone` the [vmtk repo](https://github.com/vmtk/vmtk) onto your computer and follow the [VMTK download](http://www.vmtk.org/download/) instructions on how to build it from source. It will absolutely feel like a headache and be a long process; just wait it out.

   - If you don't have cmake installed on your computer, they offer a GUI version on their website. I'm not sure how it would work for Windows, but it definitely works for Mac.
2. Once you've built it, make sure that each terminal instance of VMTK you set `source vmtk_env.sh` from the path where that file is. This will allow you to use the VMTK environment.
3. After writing the custom script, making sure to follow all the directions in the tutorial (assuming this is the first time), make sure to save it in the "site-packages" folder in the build folder. The path for me is "vmtk-build/lib/python-2.7/site-packages/vmtk/". I'm currently looking to update the version of Python it's using, but that's not the point.
4. Once that's done, navigate to that folder from within terminal and run `chmod u+x name_of_script.py` (if you're in a Unix-based operating system). This will allow you to execute the file with `./name_of_script.py`.
5. I believe it was due to the version of Python VMTK is using, but I had two "No module named" errors come up, each one a separate time: one for `tkinter` and one for `joblib`.

   - The `tkinter` issue is one that can be resolved by going into the file where the import is, I believe `vmtkscripts.py`, and changing all instances of `tkinter` to `Tkinter` (capital T). This is because they changed the name of the module from Python 2 to 3, so in newer versions of Python it would be `tkinter`. That fixed the first error.
   - When I attempted to fix the `joblib` issue, I saw that the other version of Python available on my system already had it, thus I couldn't install it through pip. Instead, you can do `python-2.7 -m pip install joblib` to install it for a specific version of Python. Although I did uninstall `joblib` as a whole from my computer before doing that.

That should fix everything. The next time I attempted to run my script, it ran without any errors.

Extra: I wasn't using any Anaconda environment for this. Might go back and try to set that up, but I'm just glad I got it to work. Additionally, I deleted the binary install of VMTK from my computer. No need to keep it around if you're just going to build it from source. You can run VMTK through the terminal after setting `source vmtk_env.sh` by running the `vmtk` command.